# Number puzzle related to the Hitchiker's Guide

Tags: cipher

So, one of my friends asked me this, because he knew I'd read The Hitchhiker's Guide to The Galaxy.

He sent me a picture of a piece of paper. It read like this;

```
                   42
                258-17-7
                424-13-9
                 23-4-18
                 24-1-17
                484-1-5
                  1-1-4
```

So I have no clue, except the first one, which is obvious

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a [book cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_cipher), where the first 42 clues The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy.

The first number represents the page, the second number represents the line (or maybe sentence), and the third number represents the word.

Unfortunately, it'll be unsolvable if you have a different type of copy (electronic, hardback, or paperback) because the pages will be different sizes.

Comment: but the book has only 224 pages according to amazon. So you mean to say that on the page number 258 is having 17 lines (which is normal for a book). So if it is a normal book then the book wont reach the page number 484.

Comment: @Manshu: Different editinos have different page counts. Also, 17 lines is normal for a book - and it can also be sentences, which can have very few words in them if people are talking.

Comment: Alright, assuming it has less number of words. Then according to you on page number 23, line 4, there exists a 18th word. which is definately not normal

Comment: @Manshu The first line of your comment has 19 words.

Comment: :p Alright sorry.. then it's a perfectly normal book...and the normal book have 224 pages.

Comment: And [the book on amazon](http://www.amazon.in/Hitchhikers-Guide-Galaxy-Douglas-Adams/dp/0345391802) have dimensions 10.6 x 1.5 x 17.4 cm, which is also normal. And the point is that you cannot compress a book that much.

Comment: @Manshu Like I pointed out, different versions of a book have different text sizes, page sizes, and page counts.

Comment: They sell at least one compilation edition containing the entire series in one book - that would easily have enough pages for this to work.  That's where I'd look if no single book has enough pages.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I have one of those. Unfortunately, page 424 is the last page of a chapter, and it doesn't have 13 lines.

Comment: Based on the first clue, has anyone considered reading these numbers in base-13?

Comment: In any version, the last word would be "the", as the opening line of the first book is "Far out in **the** uncharted..."